# Determine source of event

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a dropdown list and radio button.  If something is selected from the dropdown by the user, I want the radio button cleared.  If the radio button is selected I want the selection of the dropdown cleared.  Unfortunately, this creates events that cancel each other out.  I tried using the sender as shown below to determine if the value was being changed by code or by the user, but that doesn't work.  How do I make these events only work if the user is the source of the action?

```
private void rbBlank_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verify source of event
    if (sender is RadioButton)
    {
        // Display
        comboBoxTitles.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}


private void comboBoxTitles_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verify source of event
    if (sender is ComboBox)
    {
        // Display
        rbBlank.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `e.Source` instead of Sender.

Comment: Why do not you use DP?? Create property, and only assignment of that property will change state of one control or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to tell the difference between the two since the source will be the same instance for both occasions.

This doesn't answer the question directly but if you compare the `SelectedIndex` of comboBoxTitles in the `SelectionChanged` event handler, your problem should be solved

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxTitles.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        rbBlank.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare if sender == instance of a control instead of is type of.

```
private void rbBlank_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verify source of event
    if (sender == rbBlank)
    {
        // Display
        comboBoxTitles.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}


private void comboBoxTitles_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verify source of event
    if (sender == comboBoxTitles)
    {
        // Display
        rbBlank.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IDs of those controls, you can try something like this:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl webControl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl) sender;

if( webControl.ID == <comboboxId>)
{
//Do something
}
```

I havent tried this, but I guess it might work.